# Cordova FileTransfer Request payload form-data's name

Tags: cordova, camera, file-transfer

The application workflow is using the cordova camera getPicture and send the picture to the server by using the FileTransfer plugin.

and I check the FileTransfer request payload.
------WebKitFormBoundarychEuzGerq8dmX5zq
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="1"; filename="IMG_20160322_211023.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

the name = "1".

Then a take the second picture the name = "2".

I just wondering is there any way I can set this name for a fix value?

Please advice!

Thank you so much!

Comment: On which platform(s) is this issue appearing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the plugin docs](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/#upload) it should be configurable using `FileUploadOptions`.`fileKey`:

`fileKey: The name of the form element. Defaults to file. (DOMString)`